# TypeError: uniform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'low'/'size'

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

visualizing a neural network result and this is what shows up:

```
def apply_net(y_in):
  global w, b

  z=dot(w, y_in)+b
  return(1/(1+exp(-z)))

N0=2
N1=1 

w=random.uniform(low=-10,high=+10,size=(N1,N0)) # random weights: N1xN0
b=random.uniform(low=-1,high=+1,size=N1) #biases: N1 vector
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
2 N1=1
3
----> 4 w=random.uniform(low=-10,high=+10,size=(N1,N0)) # random weights: N1xN0
5 b=random.uniform(low=-1,high=+1,size=N1) #biases: N1 vector

TypeError: uniform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'low'

___ If I remove low and high and keep it (-10, 10, size=(N1,N0)), it says:
TypeError: uniform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'

If I remove size then it says:
TypeError: uniform() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up the documentation for [random.uniform()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform) with [numpy.uniform()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html). The numpy version takes low, high, and size as parameters, the random module only takes a and b. Surprisingly easy mistake to make, given that when I searched "python random.uniform" the numpy docs came up before the random docs

Answer (score 0):

We must use `random.uniform` while importing the related class with an alias (using 'as') or else just use `import numpy` while importing

An example for using alias is :

```
from numpy import random as np_random
```

Then utilize `np_random.uniform()`

(figured it out and had to use this to solve the problem - note I ran it on `colab`)

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the alias library or the library name directly

```
        import numpy as np
        
        def apply_net(y_in):
          global w, b
        
          z=np.dot(w, y_in)+b
          return(1/(1+np.exp(-z)))
        
        N0=2
        N1=1 
        
        w=np.random.uniform(low=-10,high=+10,size=(N1,N0)) # random weights: N1xN0
        b=np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=+1,size=N1) #biases: N1 vector
```

Comment: I did declare it in this section and also the entire notebook. The problem was a more specific alias for random.uniform. Solved it though